# getting incorrect formating when looping through ms access table data to richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, formatting, richtextbox

I have a table where the paragraph location, paragraph type and paragraph text are stored

[image]
this information is sent to a richtextbox.

So far so good

Based on the paragraph type stored in the table the paragraph text gets formatted.

It is here that it starts getting confusing

[image]

My code changes the formatting if a paragraph text is repeated.  And it will do this with every paragraph type.  I can't understand why this is happening.

What is the deal here!!!?

Thanks for your time in advance!

```
        For i = 1 To ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows.Count - 1

        rtbScriptRTF.SelectionStart = rtbScriptRTF.Text.IndexOf(rtbScriptRTF.Lines(i))
        rtbScriptRTF.SelectionLength = rtbScriptRTF.Lines(i).Length
        'MsgBox(rtbScriptRTF.SelectedText.ToString)

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 1 Then 'Action!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.Black

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 2 Then 'Dialogue!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionIndent = (rtbScriptRTF.Width / 3)
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionRightIndent = 25

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 3 Then 'Cue!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.Navy
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionIndent = (rtbScriptRTF.Width / 2)

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 4 Then 'Parenthesis!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 5 Then 'Transition IN!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 6 Then 'Transition OUT!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.Black
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 7 Then 'SLUGLINE!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.DarkRed

        End If

        If (ds.Tables("FoundSelection").Rows(i).Item("Paragraphtype")) = 8 Then 'ACT!!
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGray
            rtbScriptRTF.SelectionColor = Color.Black

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You really ought to define an `Enum` for that `ParagraphType` column. Using magic numbers like that is frowned upon because the numbers are meaningless to anyone reading the code and so it's not at all obvious if they have been used incorrectly. If you declare an `Enum` then the values are self-documenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `IndexOf`. That is going to find the first instance of the specified text. There's no need for you to find the index of anything though. Just get the `TextLength` before adding the new text and after and that's your start and end point.

```vb
Dim table = ds.Tables("FoundSelection")

For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim selectionStart = rtbScriptRTF.TextLength
    Dim selectionColor = rtbScriptRTF.ForeColor
    Dim selectionBackColor = rtbScriptRTF.BackColor
    Dim selectionIndent = 0
    Dim selectionRightIndent = 0
    Dim selectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left

    Select Case row.Field(Of Integer)("Paragraphtype")
        Case 1, 5
            selectionColor = Color.Black
        Case 2
            selectionColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen
            selectionIndent = rtbScriptRTF.Width \ 3
            selectionRightIndent = 25
        Case 3
            selectionColor = Color.Navy
            selectionIndent = rtbScriptRTF.Width \ 2
        Case 4
            selectionColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen
        Case 6
            selectionColor = Color.Black
            selectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
        Case 7
            selectionColor = Color.DarkRed
        Case 8
            selectionColor = Color.Black
            selectionBackColor = Color.LightGray
    End Select

    With rtbScriptRTF
        .AppendText(row.Field(Of String)("Paragraph"))

        Dim selectionLength = .TextLength - selectionStart

        .SelectionStart = selectionStart
        .SelectionLength = selectionLength
        .SelectionColor = selectionColor
        .SelectionBackColor = selectionBackColor
        .SelectionIndent = selectionIndent
        .SelectionRightIndent = selectionRightIndent
        .SelectionAlignment = selectionAlignment

        .AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    End With
Next
```

That code will add a paragraph and format it, add the next paragraph and format it, and so on for each paragraph.